# Comma after "that" and before the main verb

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, commas, syntax

Can I add a comma after "that" and before the main verb.

in this example, is the comma before the main verb grammatically correct?

a paper that provides an understanding of the impact of the multiple components of educational programs in various settings(**,**) has not yet been published.

Comment: Note that as well as the grammatical question you have a common mis-spelling of the word “trial”.

Comment: @MikeScott - I'd wondered about the use of trail, as though this were a path leading towards some conclusion as in a paper-trail, but had dismissed it & just ran with the ball as passed. Now you mention it, I see you're most likely right.

Comment: I have replaced it to a paper.

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably come along with more background as to why this doesn't work, but essentially you're trying to use it to separate a subordinate clause, without there being one.

In effect, you seem to be aiming for

> a trail, that provides an understanding of the impact of the multiple components of educational programs in various settings, has not yet been published.

It's not really a subordinate clause and I don't think it's necessary to separate it out in this way.

It could be a matter of opinion, but

> a man, whose hands were dirty, entered the room

could be considered subordinate; not essential to the main import of the sentence.

I'd leave it plain

> a trail that provides an understanding of the impact of the multiple components of educational programs in various settings has not yet been published.

Comment: Thank you very much.